# Resize JavaFX tab when double click

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx, javafx-8

I have this simple example with JavaFX tabs:

```
    public class test extends Application
{

    private BorderPane root;

    // Navigation Utilization
    private ActionTabs actiontabs;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {

        // Set Main Window Label
        primaryStage.setTitle("Desktop Client");
        Image iv = new Image(getClass().getResource("/images/internet-icon.png").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.getIcons().add(iv);

        root = new BorderPane();
        root.setLeft(getLeftHBox(primaryStage, root));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1000, 1000, Color.WHITESMOKE);  // Set main Stage color

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);

        Rectangle2D primaryScreenBounds = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();

        // Set Stage boundaries to visible bounds of the main screen
        primaryStage.setX(primaryScreenBounds.getMinX());
        primaryStage.setY(primaryScreenBounds.getMinY());
        primaryStage.setWidth(primaryScreenBounds.getWidth());  // Maximum width of the display
        primaryStage.setHeight(primaryScreenBounds.getHeight());    // Maximum height of the display
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

    private HBox getLeftHBox(Stage primaryStage, BorderPane root)
    {
        HBox hbox = new HBox();

        TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();
        BorderPane mainPane = new BorderPane();

        tabPane.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 12pt;"); // Set global size for the font
        // Create Tabs
        Tab tabA = new Tab();
        tabA.setText("Main Component");
        tabA.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 12pt;"); // Set size of the tab name
        tabA.setClosable(false); 
        // Add something in Tab
        StackPane tabA_stack = new StackPane();
        tabA_stack.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        tabA_stack.getChildren().add(new Label("Label@Tab A"));
        tabA.setContent(tabA_stack);
        tabPane.getTabs().add(tabA);

        Tab tabB = new Tab();
        tabB.setText("Second Component");
        tabB.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 12pt;"); // Set size of the tab name
        tabB.setClosable(false); 
        // Add something in Tab
        StackPane tabB_stack = new StackPane();
        tabB_stack.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        tabB_stack.getChildren().add(new Label("Label@Tab B"));
        tabB.setContent(tabB_stack);
        tabPane.getTabs().add(tabB);

        Tab tabC = new Tab();
        tabC.setText("Last Component");
        tabC.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 12pt;"); // Set size of the tab name
        tabC.setClosable(false); // da se mahne opciqta da se zatvarq tab
        // Add something in Tab
        StackPane tabC_vBox = new StackPane();
        tabC_vBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        tabC_vBox.getChildren().add(new Label("Label@Tab C"));
        tabC.setContent(tabC_vBox);
        tabPane.getTabs().add(tabC);

        mainPane.setCenter(tabPane);

        mainPane.setPrefSize(300, 500);
        //mainPane.setLayoutX(5);     // Horizontal Position
        mainPane.setLayoutY(32);    // Vertical Position

        hbox.getChildren().addAll(mainPane);

        return hbox;
    }


}
```

I want when I double click on a tab name to maximize the size of the body of the tab and make it the same width and height as the size of the application. Similar for example to Eclipse IDE tabs. Is this possible with JavaFX?

***EDIT***

This is the code that I have tested.

```
public BorderPane initNavigation(Stage primaryStage)
    {

        VBox stackedTitledPanes = createStackedTitledPanes();

        ScrollPane scroll = makeScrollable(stackedTitledPanes);

        final TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();
        final BorderPane mainPane = new BorderPane();

        final Rectangle2D primaryScreenBounds = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();

        tabPane.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 12pt;"); // Set global size for the font
        // Create Tabs
        Tab tabA = new Tab();

        tabPane.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>()
        {
            private double sizeX, sizeY;
            private boolean first = true;

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent me)
            {
                if (first)
                {
                    sizeX = mainPane.getWidth();
                    sizeY = mainPane.getHeight();
                    first = false;
                }

                if (me.getButton().equals(MouseButton.PRIMARY) && me.getClickCount() % 2 == 0)
                {
                    if (sizeX != mainPane.getWidth() || sizeY != mainPane.getHeight())
                    {
                        mainPane.setPrefSize(sizeX, sizeY);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        mainPane.setPrefSize(primaryScreenBounds.getWidth(), primaryScreenBounds.getHeight());
                        //mainPane.toFront();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        tabA.setText("Main Component");
        tabA.setContextMenu(makeTabContextMenu(tabA, tabPane));  // Set right mouse click menu
        // Add something in Tab
        StackPane tabA_stack = new StackPane();
        tabA_stack.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        tabA_stack.getChildren().add(scroll);
        tabA.setContent(tabA_stack);
        tabPane.getTabs().add(tabA);

        Tab tabB = new Tab();
        tabB.setText("Second Component");
        tabB.setContextMenu(makeTabContextMenu(tabB, tabPane));  // Set right mouse click menu
        // Add something in Tab
        StackPane tabB_stack = new StackPane();
        tabB_stack.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        tabB_stack.getChildren().add(new Label("Label@Tab B"));
        tabB.setContent(tabB_stack);
        tabPane.getTabs().add(tabB);

        Tab tabC = new Tab();
        tabC.setText("Last Component");
        tabC.setContextMenu(makeTabContextMenu(tabC, tabPane));  // Set right mouse click menu
        // Add something in Tab
        StackPane tabC_vBox = new StackPane();
        tabC_vBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        tabC_vBox.getChildren().add(new Label("Label@Tab C"));
        tabC.setContent(tabC_vBox);
        tabPane.getTabs().add(tabC);

        mainPane.setCenter(tabPane);
        mainPane.setPrefSize(300, 500);
        //mainPane.setLayoutX(5);     // Horizontal Position
        mainPane.setLayoutY(32);    // Vertical Position

        scroll.setPrefSize(395, 580);
        scroll.setLayoutX(5);
        scroll.setLayoutY(32);

        return mainPane;
    }
```

The problem is how I can cover the stage with the tab code when I double click on the tab name?

Comment: In your code example, the tabs are already maximized. Give an example where there are other components around the tabPane. Because it is important to know the layout of the scene, and the maximization is relative and related to this layout.

Comment: I updated the post. I have a main stage with borderpane. On the left side I have a simple tabs. How I can modify the code this way. I want when I click on the tab's name to maximize the body of the tab and fill the stage with the tabs. Similar to Eclipse when I double click on a tab name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You required to add few lines to your code, here is a sample for you,

```
.....

Tab tabA = new Tab();

Label tabALabel = new Label("Main Component");
tabA.setGraphic(tabALabel);

tabALabel.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
        if (mouseEvent.getButton().equals(MouseButton.PRIMARY)) {
            if (mouseEvent.getClickCount() == 2) {

                mainPane.setPrefSize(500, 500); //Your required size

            }
       }
    }
});

....
```

Try this, and tell if there's any difficulty.

Comment: One more question: I want the affected panel to take precedence over all other panels. For example make the panel to overlay all other panels or maybe to hide all other panels.

Comment: set your hBox which contains your mainPane to front by hbox.toFront();

Comment: if (mouseEvent.getClickCount() == 2) {

                mainPane.setPrefSize(500, 500); //Your required size
                hbox.toFront();

            }

Comment: In my case I have `BorderPane` on which the tabs are placed. I tested to use `mainPane.toFront();` but there is no effect. I get the same result.

Comment: Try adding your mainPane to Hbox as you were doing before, it was working.

Answer (score 1):

You could create another BorderPane which contains your `root = new BorderPane();`
in Center, and replace it with the Tabpanel on doubleclick.

Resulting in:

```
   rootRoot = new BorderPane();
   BorderPane  root = new BorderPane();
   root.setLeft(getLeftHBox(primaryStage, root));
   rootRoot.setCenter(root);
   Scene scene = new Scene(rootRoot, 1000, 1000, Color.WHITESMOKE);  // Set main Stage color
```

with "rootRoot" being the new root (great Name, i know ^^), and

```
    Label tabALabel=new Label("Label@Tab A");
    tabALabel.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
            if (mouseEvent.getButton().equals(MouseButton.PRIMARY)) {
                if (mouseEvent.getClickCount() == 2) {

                    //mainPane.setPrefSize(500, 500); //Your required size
                    rootRoot.setCenter(mainPane);
                }
           }
        }
    });
```

for maximizing.