# How to override components when resize component

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx, javafx-8

I tested this code which resize tab pane when the tab is double clicked.

```
tabPane.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>()
        {
            private double sizeX, sizeY;
            private boolean first = true;

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent me) 
            {
                if (first)
                {
                    sizeX = mainPane.getWidth();
                    sizeY = mainPane.getHeight();
                    first = false;
                }

                if (me.getButton().equals(MouseButton.PRIMARY) && me.getClickCount() % 2 == 0)
                {
                    if (sizeX != mainPane.getWidth() || sizeY != mainPane.getHeight())
                    {
                        mainPane.setPrefSize(sizeX, sizeY);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        mainPane.setPrefSize(primaryScreenBounds.getWidth(), primaryScreenBounds.getHeight());
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

When I double click I want to overide all other components on the main stage. How I can do this?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "override"?

Comment: I want the affected panel to take precedence over all other panels. For example make the panel to overlay all other panels or maybe to hide all other panels.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16893961/resize-javafx-tab-when-double-click/17104158?noredirect=1#comment24794462_17104158