# JavaFX AnchorPane and Tab resize and erasure of underlying screen elements

Tags: java, javafx

Re: JavaFX Anchorpane and Tab resize and erasure of underlying screen elements

After reading Stack Overflow postings -

here: 
[JavaFX Panel inside Panel auto resizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15223812/javafx-panel-inside-panel-auto-resizing)

and here: 
[Resize JavaFX tab when double click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16893961/resize-javafx-tab-when-double-click)

I was able to get the JavaFX code shown below to resize a tab to its maxium
AnchorPane allowable size; the if() block worked.  But on the else block
execution the underlying pane (main stage's scene) gets erased/clipped by the
Tab minimization.  I have looked for many hours and tried various things to refresh the main stage's screen but all UI elements are still not shown.  I could reload the stage as from the program startup but all the the user data 
on the erased screen would have to be saved, etc.

I thought about refreshing, repainting, etc., but I really don't know what to do in this case.  Like I said, I search thoroughly for this information (esp.
various stack overflow postings.)

Thanks for your comments.

```
if (mouseEvent.getClickCount() == 2) {

  if (!isTabMaximized) {

    TabPane tabPane = (TabPane) namespace.get("tabPane");
    AnchorPane applAnchorPane = 
         (AnchorPane) namespace.get("applAnchorPane");

    applAnchorPane.getChildren().forEach( node -> {

      System.out.println("Node: " + node.getId());
     });

    applAnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(tabPane, 0.0d);
    applAnchorPane.setTopAnchor(tabPane, 0.0d);
    applAnchorPane.setRightAnchor(tabPane, 0.0d);
    applAnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(tabPane, 0.0d);

    applAnchorPane.getChildren().setAll(tabPane);

    isTabMaximized = true;

  }else {

    TabPane tabPane = (TabPane) namespace.get("tabPane");
    AnchorPane applAnchorPane = 
       (AnchorPane) namespace.get("applAnchorPane");

    applAnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(tabPane, 0.0d);
    applAnchorPane.setTopAnchor(tabPane, 495.0d);
    applAnchorPane.setRightAnchor(tabPane, 0.0d);
    applAnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(tabPane, 0.0d);


    //not used commented out --> 
    // applAnchorPane.getChildren().setAll(tabPane);

    isTabMaximized = false;

    applAnchorPane.toBack();
    applAnchorPane.getChildren().forEach( node -> {
      node.toFront();
      System.out.println("Node: " + node.getId());
      node.setVisible(true);
    });

  }
```

}

---

My console output from println() in the if():

Node: mainFlowPane

My console output from println() in the else:

Node: tabPane

My fxml has the following structure (before the TabPane maximize):

AnchorPane

FlowPane   - named mainFlowPane

- HBox     - contained in FlowPane
- GridPane - contained in FlowPane
- TabPane  - contained in FlowPane, named tabPane

The FlowPane/name does not get printed in the else output to 
console, just the TabPane/name

It seems like the following has happened:
My fxml has the following structure (after the TabPane minimized):

AnchorPane

- TabPane  - contained in FlowPane, named tabPane

I debugged the code again and the FlowPane looks like it still exists.
But I get the following exception when I try to printout the FlowPane
Node fx:id's :

Node: null
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

***Here is my stacktrace:***

```
Node: null
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator$VetoableIteratorDecorator.checkForComodification(VetoableListDecorator.java:714)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator$VetoableIteratorDecorator.hasNext(VetoableListDecorator.java:682)
    at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:74)
    at wordcounterfxapp.WordCounterFXApp$4.handle(WordCounterFXApp.java:963)
    at wordcounterfxapp.WordCounterFXApp$4.handle(WordCounterFXApp.java:897)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.postProcess(Scene.java:3470)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.access$8100(Scene.java:3398)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3766)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:380)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:294)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:415)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Deleting directory C:\NetBeans\workspace8_0\WordCounterFXApp\dist\run2084430703
jfxsa-run:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 13 seconds)
```

---

---

I found that I had omitted the fx:id's from the FlowPane's HBox and GridPane:
once I added these the exception goes away.  Now my output is the following:

> jfx-project-run:
>
> Executing
>
> C:\NetBeans\workspace8_0\WordCounterFXApp\dist\run923058183\WordCounterFXApp.jar
>   using platform C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre/bin/java
>
> Before TabPane maximized - Node: applAnchorPane
>
> Before TabPane maximized - Node: mainFlowPane
>
> Before TabPane maximized - Node: flowPaneHBox
>
> Before TabPane maximized - Node: flowPaneGridPane
>
> Before TabPane maximized - Node: tabPane
>
> After TabPane minimized - Node: applAnchorPane
>
> After TabPane minimized - Node: tabPane
>
> After TabPane minimized - Node: mainFlowPane
>
> After TabPane minimized - Node: flowPaneHBox
>
> After TabPane minimized - Node: flowPaneGridPane
>
> Deleting directory
>   C:\NetBeans\workspace8_0\WordCounterFXApp\dist\run923058183
>
> jfxsa-run:
>
> BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 10 seconds)

This printout shows that the FlowPane with its child Nodes are pushed
below the TabPane?

So, this might show what's going on.  That the FlowPane might be outside of
the visible region.  At this point I don't know how to fix it however...

---

10/26/2016

To wrap up this debugging exercise...

The problem: JavaFX AnchorPane and Tab resize and erasure of underlying screen elements

The analysis: On TabPane minimization, the JavaFx UI does not render my FlowPane
properly with its 3 nodes of structure:

AnchorPane

FlowPane   - named mainFlowPane

- HBox     - contained in FlowPane
- GridPane - contained in FlowPane
- TabPane  - contained in FlowPane, named tabPane

On TabPane maximization, the UI relocates the TabPane Node from
within the FlowPane to under the AnchorPane.  On minimization the
following Node hierachy results:

AnchorPane

- TabPane  - contained in FlowPane, named tabPane

FlowPane   - named mainFlowPane

- HBox     - contained in FlowPane
- GridPane - contained in FlowPane

Thus, the JavaFx UI places the TabPane as shown.  And, thus,
the FlowPane with its Node elements are pushed out of UI 
stage/scene visual display.  Why does the UI do this, rather
than relocate/minimize the display, and not move the TabPane
Node???

The solution:

I found a solution, with adding two lines of code at end of the else block:

> > > flowPane.getChildren().add(tabPane);
> > >
> > > applAnchorPane.getChildren().add(flowPane);

I have done some investigation so the UI should be fixed for now.  I am now able to do both maximize and minimize a TabPane with is associated Tab Nodes.  As far as I can tell, the JavaFx Node hierarchy is now the same after a min/max Tab as the Node structure was before these 2 operations.  The problem was probably not a coding issue.  Should JavaFx UI render things the way it does, to re-order the various nodes?  I could not find any documentation for this in about 5-7 hours of research.  Hopefully, my notes about this will help others in a similar situation.

Thanks to Blip/StackExchange commentor, I was able to debug this issue to a successful outcome.  Hat's off to Blip!  Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Did you get any kind of error or exception?

Comment: Thanks for your response.  No, I did not get either an error or exception.

Comment: how are you running the program? are you using an ide?

Comment: I'm using NetBeans, latest Dev. version.  I updated the IDE

Comment: in the last month or so

Comment: in the console window see if there is any error or exception shown

Comment: Like I said, none are shown.

Comment: jfx-project-run:
Executing C:\NetBeans\workspace8_0\WordCounterFXApp\dist\run1167502575\WordCounterFXApp.jar using platform C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre/bin/java
Deleting directory C:\NetBeans\workspace8_0\WordCounterFXApp\dist\run1167502575
jfxsa-run:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 42 seconds)

Comment: The attached console is what's output.

Comment: ok. but does anything extra gets printed when you want to resize by double clicking the maximized tabPane

Comment: No, nothing extra is printed.

Comment: Also I tried the following (java 8):

Comment: applAnchorPane.toBack();       /* Is the issue is z-order problem? - No*/     applAnchorPane.getChildren().forEach( node ->
      node.setVisible(true)

Comment: And nothing is displayed in the erased area of the app

Comment: I would suggest to add a `printLn` inside the body of the `else` and check whether this is getting printed in the console or not. If it gets written then the else is executing otherwise the else is not executing. Also you could add break points in the else loop and then run the program in debug. This will help you the peep into the instances and their propertied.

Comment: did you try what I suggested?

Comment: Yes, I did.  I have added notes in body.  Looks like my FlowPane is missing. It contained a couple of Node's before the TabPane.  In the else block the AnchorPane only prints out the TabPane as a child not the missing FlowPane container.  The FXML structure is highlighted. The FlowPane is totally gone, it's fx:id is not printed.

Comment: please edit your code that you have posted as to where and how you have added the printlns

Comment: The println 's are in the logic above and discussed in the accompanying notes.

Comment: post the complete stacktrace

Comment: post the code how you got this exception

Comment: I found the problem that caused the stacktrace.  The fx:id 's for the FlowPane's Node's were missing.  See the notes after the stacktrace.  The FlowPane is pushed below the TabPane after the Tab minimization takes place.  This describes the problem, maybe, and the println's output show the resulting structure.  I don't quite know how to fix this however.  I would have thought that the underlying rendering would have placed the TabPane to its original place in the Node heirachy.

Comment: is the node hierarchy `AnchorPane` contains `FlowPane` contains `HBox`, `GridPane` and `TabPane` initially? Also does the `AnchorPane` have any Bounds set to it?

Comment: Blip - thanks for helping/shadowing me with this problem.  I found a solution, with adding two lines of code at end of the else block:           ->>>           flowPane.getChildren().add(tabPane);
->>>>         applAnchorPane.getChildren().add(flowPane);                                           I  will still do some investigation but the UI should be fixed for now.  Thanks for your questions.  They proved to be helpful in debugging this issue.  Have a wonderful day!        - JD from Seattle